# llenar tabla html

Tags: javascript

buenas tardes estoy intentado llenar una tabla a partir de un formulario con java script  pero no para la cuando creo una celda con insertCell y quiero asignarle el valor de un campo de mi formulario no funciona. No se que estoy haciendo mal

```js
formulario.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  var table = document.getElementById("detalles_venta");
  var row = table.insertRow(0);
  var celda1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var celda2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var celda3 = row.insertCell(2);
  var celda4 = row.insertCell(3);
  var celda5 = row.insertCell(3);
  var celda6 = row.insertCell(3);

  celda1.innerHTML(codigo.value);
  celda2.innerHTML(selectproducto.value);
  celda3.innerHTML(precio.value);
  celda4.innerHTML(cantidad.value);
  celda5.innerHTML(iva.value);
  celda6.innerHTML(total.value);
});
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover" id="detalles_venta">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Producto</th>
      <th>Descripcion</th>
      <th>Precio</th>
      <th>Cantidad</th>
      <th>Iva</th>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th>Accion</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>

    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: ¿Puedes agregar tu formulario?

Comment: ¿Estas usando Jquery?

Comment: De donde sale el formulario?

Answer (score 0):

remito mi formulario

```
             <form action="" method="POST" id="formulario_compras" >
                 <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="" class="col-4 col-form-label">Producto</label>
                    
                    <select class="combobox form-control col-4 " name="codigo_producto" id="codigo_producto">
                                               
                    </select> 
                </div>    
                 
                 <div class="form-group row">
                     <label  class="col-4 col-form-label">Codigo</label>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control col-4" id="codigo"  disabled> 
                 </div>
                 <div class="form-group row">
                     <label  class="col-4 col-form-label">Precio</label>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control col-4" id="precio"  disabled> 
                 </div>           
                <div class="form-group row">
                     <label  class="col-4 col-form-label ">Cantidad</label>
                     <input type="number"  class="form-control col-4" id="cantidad"> 
                 </div> 
                   <div class="form-group row">
                     <label class="col-4 col-form-label">Iva</label>
                     <input type="number"  class="form-control col-4" id="iva" disabled >
                 </div> 
                 <div class="form-group row">
                     <label class="col-4 col-form-label">Total</label>
                     <input type="number"  class="form-control col-4" id="total" disabled >
                 </div> 
                 
                    <input class="boton offset-md-4" type="submit" name="accion" value="ACEPTAR">                                      
                                                        
                 
             </form>
```

Answer (score -2):

le voy a dejar un ejemplo mucho la estructurado, utiliza Jquery en la cual utilizar la funcion  append

```js
$(document).on('click', '#add', function() {
var data = 'todos'
var data2 = 'todas'

  $('#postTable').append("<tr><td class='col1'>" + data + "</td>"+
  "<td class='col1'>" + data2 + "</td>"+

 "</tr>")

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="massshow-modal btn btn-success" id="add"> Añadir</button>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover compact nowrap" id="postTable">
   <tr>
       <td>ID</td>
       <td>ID2</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Pero si no pone la etiqueta jquery, solo pone javascript